# Understanding the principles of moving along routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I have routes:

```
'/home'
'/home/nav_one'
'/home/nav_one/nav_two'
'/home/contacts'
'/home/contacts/description'
```

and the transitions were made:

```
'/home' -> '/home/nav_one' -> '/home/nav_one/nav_two' -> '/home/contacts/description'
```

Where will the command return: Navigator.pop():
To `'/home/nav_one/nav_two'` or `'/home/contacts'`?

If in the first option, then why do we write these same routes, for the sake of ease of reading and understanding?

Comment: It's not compulsory to repeat. You can write whatever you want, that makes clear and understandable to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these are the route names and that you've been `Navigator.pushNamed()`ing the screens the answer is,

To `'/home/nav_one/nav_two'`

These route names are just identifiers so you can name them like,

```
'/home'
'/nav_one'
'/nav_two'
'/contacts'
'/description'
```

for your own convenience.